# How can I add a option to a GameObject in the Hierarchy context menu?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class Test : EditorWindow
{
    [MenuItem("GameObject/Test")]
    static void Tests()
    {
        int width = 340;
        int height = 300;

        int x = (Screen.currentResolution.width - width) / 2;
        int y = (Screen.currentResolution.height - height) / 2;

        GetWindow<Test>().position = new Rect(x, y, width, height);
    }
}
```

This will create the Test option in the editor menu on the top under GameObject.
But I want to add option/property on a single or more GameObject/s in the Hierarchy not the editor top menu.

This is what I tried:

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class ExportObjects : EditorWindow
{
    [MenuItem("GaemObject/Export", true, 1)]
    static void Export()
    {
        int width = 340;
        int height = 300;

        int x = (Screen.currentResolution.width - width) / 2;
        int y = (Screen.currentResolution.height - height) / 2;

        GetWindow<ExportObjects>().position = new Rect(x, y, width, height);
    }
}
```

But it does nothing it didn't add anything to the right click mouse context menu on the objects in the hierarchy.

If I change the line:

```
[MenuItem("GaemObject/Export", true, 1)]
```

To:

```
[MenuItem("GaemObject/Export")]
```

It will add a new GameObject menu at the top of the editor and the Export.
But I want to add this when doing right click mouse on a object in the hierarchy. Single object or for selected objects.

Tried true, 1 and true, -10 or true, 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this post](http://answers.unity.com/answers/810239/view.html) it depends on more parameters. it will appear in the hierarchy context menu using the `priority` parameter e.g. with `-10`

```
[MenuItem("GameObject/Test", false, -10)]
```

There is no option to control for which objects this shall be displayed or not.

But you can enable and disable the button by adding a validation method. E.g only enable the method if the selected object has a `Camera` component

```
// true turns it into a validation method
[MenuItem("GameObject/Test", true, -10)]
private static bool IsCanera()
{
    return Selection.activeGameObject != null && Selection.activeGameObject.GetComponent<Camera>();
}
```

---

The same way but using [`[ContextMenu]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ContextMenu.html) instead you can add it to the component in the Inspector

```
[ContextMenu("Example")]
private void DoSomething()
{
    // Do something
}
```

---

You can also add a method directly to the context menu of only one field in the Inspector using [`[ContextMenuItem]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ContextMenuItemAttribute.html)

```
[ContextMenuItem("reset this", "ResetExample")]
public int example;

private void ResetExample ()
{
    example = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look here https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PresetManager.html

You can use this to change the default components added to an object for generic objects or create a preset for a new type of asset or object

You will need to create the component which would simply be a script